# AWS Toolkit for Eclipse Installation fails on Eclipse Luna 4.4

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software currently installed: AWS CodeStar Plugin 1.0.0.v201707121824 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.codestar.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.v201707121824)
Missing requirement: AWS CodeCommit Plugin 1.0.0.v201707121824 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.codecommit 1.0.0.v201707121824) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.ui.navigator 3.5.401' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: AWS CodeStar Plugin 1.0.0.v201707121824 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.codestar 1.0.0.v201707121824)
To: bundle com.amazonaws.eclipse.codecommit 1.0.0
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: AWS CodeStar Plugin 1.0.0.v201707121824 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.codestar.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.v201707121824)
To: com.amazonaws.eclipse.codestar [1.0.0.v201707121824]

Answer (score 1):

This is saying that the install needs at least version 3.5.401 of the org.eclipse.ui.navigator plugin. Eclipse Luna 4.4.0 only has version 3.5.400 of this plugin.

The 4.4.2 maintenance release of Luna does have version of 3.5.401 of this plugin so you need to update to that (or move to a newer version of Eclipse such as the current Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.0).

Answer (score 0):

If it is Spring STS IDE ; you can goto Help -> About spring tool Suite -> Installation Details button will be there,
Click that one window will be poped-up. Click on "Update"

Hope this works for Eclipse based IDE's